# How can I copy a file even if my Build fails from POM

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I want to copy a file from my source directory to another in **verify** Phase  even if the build failed. Im able to copy the file using '**exec-maven-plugin**' . But issue is , if a test failure happens, the verify phase is skipping . I know its maven default property. But is there any way I can achieve that?

thanks
Sujee

Comment: Not very familiar with Maven, but can you do it in an earlier phase?

Comment: The verify phase won't be reached if an earlier phase fails. Tell us why you need it done in the verify phase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [maven-resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) and tie it to post-clean phase

Comment: Oops. My bad..But it is working fine only with initial phases. I strictly want to use it in "verify" phase. How can I achieve that.

Comment: Do you create any files in the source folder during the verify phase so that you have to specifically do the copy after the verify?